# Button from a dynamically added html tag does not invoke ng-click in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make my button from an appended html work using the ng-click event. I have seen some solutions here but it seems not to work for me. Probably because I have a different situation or I just couldn't use it right. My codes are below:

**fileMaintenanceCtrl.js**

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />

angular.module('adminApp')
.controller('fileMaintenance', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce, $compile) {

        // Adding Client

        $scope.addNewClient = function () {
            debugger;
            alert($scope.addClient.CompanyName);
        }

        // End of adding client


// This is how I get the html template            
$scope.addClient = function () {
                $http.get('/FileMaintenance/AddClient')
                    .then(function(response) {
                            var divTemplate = response.data;
                            var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('btnAddCompany'));
                            console.log(element.toString());
                            element.append(divTemplate);
                            $compile(element)($scope);
                      },
                        function(error) {
                            alert('An error occured in retrieving view. ' + error.message);
                        });
            };
        }
    ]);
```

**addClient.cshtml**

```
<h1 class="text-center text-info">Add Client</h1>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <form role="form" name="formAddClient">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCompany">Company</label>
                <input id="inputCompany" type="text"
                       class="form-control" ng-model="addClient.CompanyName" name="CompanyName"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputContactPerson">Contact Person</label>
                <input id="inputContactPerson" type="text"
                       class="form-control" ng-model="addClient.contact_person" name="ContactPerson"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmailAddress">Email Address</label>
                <input id="inputEmailAddress" type="text"
                       class="form-control" ng-model="addClient.email_address" name="EmailAddress"/>
            </div>
        </form>

        <input type="button" id="btnAddCompany" class="btn btn-success"
               value="Add Company" ng-click="addNewClient()"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

**fileMaintenance.cshtml** <-- this is where I place the html template

```
<div class="active tab-pane" id="file_maintenance">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="addClient()">Add Client</a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="file_maintenance_view_area">
        <div ng-bind-html="chosen_view">

        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of tab file_maintenance -->
```

I also tried this code:

```
$scope.addClient = function () {
    $http.get('/FileMaintenance/AddClient')
        .then(function(response) {
            var divTemplate = response.data;
            var temp = $compile(divTemplate)($scope);
            var ele = angular.element(document.getElementById('btnAddCompany')).append(temp);
        },
            function(error) {
                alert('An error occured in retrieving view. ' + error.message);
            });
};
```

but if I do it like this code, I can't even get my template html to show.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you, but it is a big no-no for the controller to modify the DOM directly.  You may need a custom directive here.

Comment: Yes. I actually saw this 'directive' the problem is, I am new to angular and I do not want to complicate it. I can't get to run the program currently.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ng-if` to dynamically include/exclude your HTML content, and then bind it to your controller?  I agree that directives can be a bit ugly, and may not be your first choice.

Comment: I just get the html template according to the button I click. If I have 2 buttons, I just change the view accordingly.

Comment: @stackquestions You need to change the way you think about how applications work. Don't download HTML. Download data, as JSON. The HTML should be, statically, in your template. And it should display the data you download. If you need to choose what to display depending on what you download, then simply use ng-if or ng-switch to choose what to display depending on what the data contains.

Comment: Thanks for ponting that out JB. I want to add my form tag and its elemen to a div in my main html and I need to do it on a button click. If I do not download the view and render it to the div in the main, how do I do it statically as you've mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `$compile` *after* the snippet is injected :

```js
.then(function(response) {
   var divTemplate = response.data;
   var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('btnAddCompany'));
   element.append(divTemplate);
   $compile(element)($scope);
},
```

`append()` only append a string which when is parsed and inserted to the DOM. It does not consider links you have made to the `$scope`.

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect what you suggested. How do I place the compiled element to the main view? The way i did it before was to place the html codes in a variable and bind the variable to the main view.

Comment: That variable is `$scope.chosen_view`

Comment: @stackquestions, I do not follow what you mean with "main view"?? here is a plunkr demonstrating the above, simplified -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/nAtJV6hSz512uKorAxkD?p=preview**

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is the partial view is not rendered in the main view. The way I get the view or html tags to append to my main view before is using the ng-bind-html="chosen_view". This way I get the input fields and the button, but the button does not work. Applying your solution, I do not get the partial view anymore. Probably it is not being bound to the ng-bind-html="chosen_view"

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I've seen it now when I used your plnkr. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!

Comment: @stackquestions  OK :) I looked at the other approach, you face a sanitize problem, angular will strip directives out when using `angular-sanitize`, and by that there is nothing to `$compile`. I mean, when you have assigned `divTemplate` to `chosen_view`, and it is rendered, directives like `ng-click` is removed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do I still have to use directives for this?

Comment: @stackquestions No, I would just do as above. The reason for sanitizing is so you can insert HTML without worrying about the content. I use `ng-bind-html` with article texts, user abouts and so on, saved in a database by for example users, and they should not be able to sneak malicious code into the view. But when you have some HTML you want to inject, like a template, and it should work along with the rest of the code, use $compile as above.